# How to get a particular reviewer vote in Gerrit prolog not via rest api?

Tags: git, jenkins, prolog, gerrit

I have a gerrit jenkins suport.
I am unable to find a solution in gerrit prolog documentation https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working according to below scenario

1- When jenkins user give a -1 vote, It will disable the Submit button

2- When jenkins user gives +1 vote, it will enable the Submit button.

```
submit_rule(S) :-
    gerrit:default_submit(X),
    X =.. [submit | Ls],
    add_non_author_approval(Ls, R),
    S =.. [submit | R].

score(Category, Score) :-
    gerrit:commit_label(label(Category, Score), user(1000002)).

add_non_author_approval(S1, S2) :-
    gerrit:commit_label(label('Code-Review', 1), user(1000001)),
    A = user(1000002),
    gerrit:commit_label(label('Code-Review', 2), R),
    R \= A, !,
    S2 = [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', ok(R)) | S1].

add_non_author_approval(S1, [label('Non-Author-Code-Review', need(_)) | S1]).
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution to this! You can simplify this slightly: `X =.. [submit|Ls]` is exactly the same as: `X = submit(Ls)`. Similarly, `S = submit(R)`.

Comment: @mat I am new to prolog. Thanks for highlighting those optimization.

Comment: You can make these changes to your answer!